# Sorting Entry Query Related By Custom Field

Tags: craft3

I am currently trying to speed up a website I work on, and would like to implement pagination as an index page is currently loading over 350 entries.

Each entry has a relation to another which holds data which is shared between different groups of entries.

On this website this takes the form of a store of yachts which holds all the data about them, from the price to the length and their images, these entries are then linked to from other entries for pages where that information is needed to be displayed, for example a yacht might be linked to from a sales page, or a charter page.

Within these parent entries for example charter there is an index page which displays all the yachts and is filterable.

The first query shown here shown how we are filtering the yachts down, this query will specifically query the underlying yacht data and return the ID's of all the yachts which match: https://pastebin.com/kK4gsWM4

The second query shown here takes the ID's of the yachts found above and finds the parent entries which are related of the correct type in this case charter: https://pastebin.com/TkyV6fxy

The issue is that I cannot sort the parent entries by the information contained within the yachts, for example I would like to sort by the length or price of the yacht.

To get round this I am currently using https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/SuperSort to sort the results after they have been returned.

This means however I cannot paginate the results as the sorting is done after the results have been returned.

So my question is, is there a way to order the parent entries by the values contained within the shared yacht entries?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!